# General strategies for debugging model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, debugging

When coding a standard program in a text editor there are many tools for debugging problems (syntax errors, debuggers, logging information to the console, unit tests, etc.)

What are some ways to do these things in model builder? Is it possible?  Should I just use the Python API instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to describe the precise circumstance that you are referring to, please?  ModelBuilder becomes quite easy to debug with experience so I suspect you are just having teething problems.  A picture of the relevant part of your model or some more words describing how you are trying to put that part together will help.  I will +1 your Question in case you need a little more rep to add a picture easily.  I prefer Python/ArcPy to ModelBuilder but the latter meets many requirements too.

Comment: "Should I just use the Python API instead?" A big YES. ModelBuilder is, to be frank, rubbish. Although you will still have to be aware of the data types in geoprocessing as well as the expected arguments, but this is all documented in the help system.

Comment: Another possibility if you aren't familiar with Python already is FME or the Data Interoperability Extension, which has a graphical modeling environment like ModelBuilder, just a lot better. You can literally debug connections in it using inspection points. It also has far more verbose and (usually) helpful logging than ModelBuilder.

Comment: Hi, I reworded my question hopefully that helps.  I'm looking for some analogous tools to the ones I use to develop standard software, just applied to model builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you are asking for is not really feasible or applicable to ModelBuilder. Either it works or it doesn't. Sometimes you get useful error messages, other times you just have to tweak things, futz around, send in bug reports, stand on one leg, make ritual sacrifices to the ModelBuilder gods, etc.

There are a couple of useful "debugging" tips I found in this [presentation](http://www.junipergis.com/files/4312/5952/9470/ModelBuilder.pdf):

> - Validating and debugging a Model
>
>   - Models can be Validated.
>   - Validation won’t provide messages; elements with errors will turn blank.
>   - Right-clicking tools accesses “View Messages” which describes the error.
>   - The fix is usually to reset parameters for that tool.
>   - Running a Model opens the process dialog, and any errors encountered are shown in red.
>
>     - Scroll through the entire dialog box, as
>         there could be several errors.
>   - Most common errors are that even when “Overwrite outputs of geoprocessing
>       operations” is set, ArcGIS doesn’t always overwrite files.
>
>     - Potential fix is to delete intermediate data.
>   - Another problem is when files share the 1st same 13 characters, ArcGIS sometimes thinks there is only one file, and may inadvertently delete a file.

Some things are just so much more difficult to do in ModelBuilder than they are in a programming language like Python. Looping in ModelBuilder (variously handled with iterators, batch mode, the iteration properties tab, feedback variables, etc.) is often maddening compared to just writing a for loop in Python.

Also, the way you document processes in ModelBuilder (which was never a fun experience) has undergone somewhat of an upheaval between version 9.3 and version 10.0. [This thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8466-How-do-you-document-a-process-in-model-builder-for-ArcGIS-10) has more information.

You might be able to use Python within ModelBuilder's [Calculate Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v8000000) tool to log certain steps but it's not really worth it because of how fiddly it is. And at that point you might as well be using Python exclusively.

All that being said, I still use ModelBuilder occasionally, only because I am very familiar with it and other people in my organization use it. Its strengths are with data and parameter types that can be complex to manage in arcpy, such as rasters, field mappings, value tables etc. It's also very easy to just throw something together quickly, as long as it is simple.

Additionally you'll often have to work with people that are less savvy with programming and rely on ModelBuilder for their work. If you have a substantial library of [script tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_tools_with_Python/00150000002q000000/), then integrating those with ModelBuilder is also fairly straightforward.

If you can help it though, I would avoid it completely :)